# opevCV download Python

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

While trying to download Opencv over the CMD I got this message:

> 1% |Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence

How should I download the Opencv folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows this might be related to the issue reported on Github for pip ([link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5665)). It's an issue Python has with locales/text encoding on Windows. This results in issues when pip attempts to show a progress bar. Some workarounds mention to turn off the progress bar:

```
pip install <package> -q  # quite mode
pip install <package> --progress-bar off  # only hide the progress bar
```